How long should a direct quote be in order to be put in quotation marks?
Let's suppose there is a short definition in a source and that I want to report such definition in a paper but adapting the initial wording to the sentence.
For instance

Definition: a bottle is a container made of an impermeable material that stores and transports liquids.

(this is from Wikipedia by the way, but assume it's copied verbatim from another source, called Source A).
In my paper I want to write

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles are containers made of an impermeable material that stores and transport liquids. [Source A]

I know I have to cite the source of the definition (Source A) but should I use the quotation marks for direct quotes in this case even if the part "copied and pasted" is extremely short (less than a sentence)? Should I write the following?

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles are containers "made of an impermeable material that stores and transport liquids." [SourceA]

It seems overly pedantic to me, but I would like to be sure of that to avoid committing plagiarism.

Pedant's note: Bottles can also be used to store and transport solids or gases (and when they are "empty" they are implicitly storing a gas).

Speaking of pedantry, it's worth paying attention to the verb-subject agreement. In the original version, it is the container that stores liquids. In your versions, the implication is that the impermeable material stores liquids, but this makes little sense - the same material in a non-container shape might not keep any liquid inside it.

Tangential issue, but there's a logic error here: the quote doesn't support the claim made. Consider the one-word replacement: "There are multiple containers used for carrying lava. For instance, bottles are containers made of an impermeable material that store and transport liquids." or "There are multiple containers used for housing sharks. For instance, fishbowls are bowls for the keeping of live fish." The fact that bottles can contain certain liquids, does not necessarily imply that they can contain the liquid under discussion. So you'd be better off finding a more specific quote.

@Ben Pedanter's note: Bottles are jars with a curving neck. Jars can be used to transport anything.


It seems overly pedantic to me

It's not overly pedantic. There is an actual difference between the information conveyed by

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles are containers "made of an impermeable material that stores and transport liquids." [SourceA]

versus

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles are containers made of an impermeable material that stores and transport liquids. [SourceA]

Both of these formulations tell the reader that you are relying on "SourceA" as the reference for your definition of bottles. But the second one indicates that you have rephrased the definition from SourceA in your own words. The first one indicates that the quoted part comes verbatim from SourceA.
Depending on the context, it may be fine (and even sometimes preferable) to paraphrase the definition in your own words. Wanting to keep the discussion somewhat informal, or wanting to avoid giving an "overly pedantic" vibe, or just plain preferring your own way of saying things to that of the source, are all valid reasons to paraphrase. But as long as you are echoing verbatim the phrasing of the source, you need to indicate that this is a quotation. In formal writing, double quotes are the standard way to do this, but note that there are other ways to indicate quotations, such as the one used here on Stack Exchange:

This is a quote.
      -Abraham Lincoln


"This is a quote." [citation needed].

“This is a quote.” [Dan Romik, personal correspondence] - is that better @Buffy?

Note: single quotes are acceptable for indicating a quotation in British English. ‘I don’t know if this is also true in other varieties of English’ - Neil Tarrant (2024)

@NeilTarrant The problem with using single quotes is that they have a specific function. You use them when you have a quote within a quote. e.g. "Note: single quotes are acceptable for indicating a quotation in British English. ‘I don’t know if this is also true in other varieties of English’"  - Neil Tarrant (2024)

@NeilTarrant For whatever reason, this is the exact opposite of British English.

@MiniRagnarok If the world were logical, Australians would use non-inverted commas. :)

@MiniRagnarok it’s a little more subtle. In British English you can use either single or double quotes, and then alternate for nested quotations.  Double quotes are maybe a little more common as the first level of quotation, but both are acceptable.

There's another difference between your two examples. The second, without quotes, fails to make clear how much of the paragraph is being cited. Is Source A also responsible for the information that there are multiple containers used for carrying water?

I would recommend either rephrasing the entire sentence and leaving it unquoted, or quoting it with a [bracketed] inline edit, as: For instance, bottles are containers "made of an impermeable material that [store] and transport liquids." [SourceA] - otherwise, because "bottles" is plural here but singular in the source, the quote looks like it's talking only about the storage capability of the material, rather than the bottle.

@DewiMorgan good suggestion, I hadn't noticed that issue. This grammatical mismatch could be another valid reason to paraphrase the definition instead of quoting it.

"This" [Oxford dictionary] "is" [Cambridge dictionary] "a" [Abraham Lincoln] "quote" [Dan Romik]

i was embarrassed to be told after my MA exam that my quotation marks were all wrong in my bibliography. Only later did I discover that they were perfectly acceptable in British English, but that the American examiner was apparently unaware of this. (I was in the US, but other varieties of English were perfectly acceptable provided one was consistent and I was using British punctuation and spelling throughout.)

Yes, you should put direct quotations (that are less than 40 words) in quotation marks, even if it is just one word. See the examples on the American Psychological Association website. The direct quotation in quotation marks is just 13 words.
In your case, you are quoting a definition. The site I linked to states "Use direct quotations rather than paraphrasing: when reproducing an exact definition [...], when an author has said something memorably or succinctly, or when you want to respond to exact wording [...]."

I disagree about the "just one word" part.  It's just silly.

I agree with the "just one word" part.  Example ... Freud used the terms "id", "ego" and "superego".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To reiterate the other answers, the length of the citation is irrelevant -- quotation marks are used to indicate that you got the text (definition, word, phrase, sentence, or paragraph) from somewhere else, and did not put it in your own words.
Thus:

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, a bottle is "made of an impermeable material that stores and transports liquids." [SourceA]

is correct (slightly modified from yours for clarity), whereas

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles are containers made of an impermeable material that stores and transports liquids. [Source A]

is incorrect, and finally, something like

There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, bottles can be used to store and transport liquids including water. [Source A]

would also be correct. In the last example, we have reworded to put the definition in context and only kept the part(s) that are actually need for our own point. Of course, we still need the citation as it is the supporting material for this information. Consider which is clearest for your own purposes.

It seems overly pedantic to me

It is! After all, the point of formal writing is to be pedantic about every detail :)

The first example is not correct, because it fundamentally changes and misrepresents the quoted text. In order to make it an adequate quote, “stores and transports” (which you silently changed to “stores and transport”) should be changed to “[store] and [transport]” – or alternatively, the subject should be made singular to match the source (“For instance, a bottle is ‘a container… that stores and transports liquids…’”). As Anyon’s comment to the question says, it’s the bottle that stores and transports liquids, not the impermeable material.

@JanusBahsJacquet Should be fixed now, thanks. (Though as to bottle vs material, IMHO the Wikipedia quote could probably be read either way.)

"the length of the citation is irrelevant" - until you get long enough to use block quotes.  These provide another way of making an exact quote obvious, if done correctly.

Yes, you should put quotation marks around the part you are quoting directly. The amount of text you are quoting is well within the range that you would be expected to mark as a direct quote. Sometimes when adapting the wording of a definition slightly, you will still need to quote it but with the changes marked with square brackets: []
For example:
There are multiple containers used for carrying water. For instance, "[bottles are containers] made of an impermeable material that [store] and transport liquids." [SourceA]
This shows that the "bottles are containers" part is essentially part of the quote, but that you have adapted it slightly to fit the grammar of the sentence. I don't think this is necessary in your example, but can be useful when you are quoting a definition and need to change the tense. As noted in the comments, it gets pretty clunky in this example and you'd probably be better off rephrasing the start of the sentence to be more in line with the original quote, or rephrasing the whole thing.

Should also replace "stores" with [store], here. Better off, at that point, either changing the start of the sentence to be more in line with the original quote, or rephrasing the whole thing.

If you copied the wording verbatim from a specific source, you need to either use quotation marks around the copied text or put it in a block quote. The length of the quote only affects the type of quoting ("inline quotes" for short ones or block quotes for longer ones, specifics varying by style guide).
This may mean you're quoting single words or short phrases, such as when the author is using words in a way unique to their paper. This may also mean that a verbatim phrase in your paper may happen to appear in a source you used but not require quotes because it is very, very generic, to the point that it could appear in any paper on the topic. For example, a phrase like "Shakespeare's last work, The Tempest, was..." is generic enough that multiple authors are likely to come up with it verbatim (and a search suggests they did).
If you're in doubt, paraphrase instead.
Quote formatting (or lack thereof), when done properly, conveys a lot of information about the original text. For example, for MLA that includes:

Original capitalization
Whether or not the beginning of the sentence was quoted
If words were omitted mid-quote
Original verb forms

Some of the examples they give would look more elegant if they put even a single small word (like "an") from the quote outside of the quote marks, but they didn't. (MLA, however, is more extreme in their rules for bracketing than other guides.)

There are three options for you:

Paraphrase. Give the information using your own words. Then there are no quotes and you refer the author of the idea/conclusion. [Citation]
Short direct quote. Copy the text verbatim. Then you need to emphasize the text is not your own by using quotes. As deee said: "Yes, you should put quotation marks around the part you are quoting directly." [dee]
Long direct quotes. Copy the text verbatim. Use different paragraph style to emphasize the difference (usually different margins serve well).


"Yes, you should put quotation marks around the part you are quoting directly."
-[dee]

Note that there is pedantic issue (my novel ideas / others' ideas / others' words verbaim) and aesthetic issue. If you have one two-sentence quote in the whole paper and the rest are few-words quotes, there is no need to introduce the paragraph. On the othe hand, if you have mainly long quotes, I'd put even few words in special paragraph. Just to keep it consistent.
Also note that the special paragraph gives the quote a punch.
